# Java/Android- How to use ObjectOutputStream to write a large size of List object in TCP/IP socket programming

Tags: java, sockets, arraylist, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I recently use ObjectOutputStream to write objects in TCP/IP socket programming.

If I want to write a large size of `List<Object>/ArrayList<Object>` through the socket

(e.g. list.size: 100, the total bytes may larger than the payload size),

should I just call `writeObject(List<Object>/ArrayList<Object>)`?

Is that OK, or any Exception occurs?

Does ObjectOutputStream automatically split the list to a few segments before sending the packets? Or it doesn't support?

Is there another way to send a large size of an object?

As for ObjectInputStream, can I just call `readObject()` to receive the large size of `List<Object>/ArrayList<Object>`?

Thanks in advance.

->

Another questions: Does ObjectInputStream receive anything when the list is not fully sent from the sender? 
I want to close the socket but the ObjectOutputStream is still sending the list. Does it shutdown immediately when I close socket, and the list segments are destroyed?

Answer (score 1):

> Is that OK, or any Exception occurs?
>   It's ok.
>
> Does ObjectOutputStream automatically split the list to a few segments

Yes.

> before sending the packets? Or it doesn't support?

The underlying socket has no control over how packets are sent. Nor should you need it.

> Is there another way to send a large size of an object?

Many but 100 isn't very large.  If you had a few million of large objects it might be worth it. If you have a few billion you definitively need to consider alternatives.  There is lots of alternatives but I wouldn't bother unless you need it.

> As for ObjectInputStream, can I just call readObject() to receive the large size of List/ArrayList?

Yes, that is what it is for.

Comment: Another questions: Does ObjectInputStream receive anything when the list is not fully sent from the sender? 
I want to close the socket but the ObjectOutputStream is still sending the list. Does it shutdown immediately when I close socket, and the list segments are destroyed?

Answer (score 1):

> should I just call `writeObject(List<Object>/ArrayList<Object>)?`

Yes.

> Is that OK, or any Exception occurs?

It is OK, but exceptions can always occur, especially over a network.

> Does `ObjectOutputStream` automatically split the list to a few segments before sending the packets? Or it doesn't support?

Yes, and TCP does as well, and IP.

> Is there another way to send a large size of an object?

Why? You have this way. You don't need another way.

> As for `ObjectInputStream,` can I just call `readObject()` to receive the large size of `List<Object>/ArrayList<Object>?`

Yes.

Comment: Another questions: Does ObjectInputStream receive anything when the list is not fully sent from the sender? 
I want to close the socket but the ObjectOutputStream is still sending the list. Does it shutdown immediately when I close socket, and the list segments are destroyed?

Comment: You will get an `EOFException` if the object isn't fully received before end of stream.